# ReactJs, strugglig again

Tags: reactjs

There is something I really don't understand in reacts and sometime the behaviors seem more about bug features that what is expected.

I was testing an instantiation by array. What is strange that the first time, it work as expected.

```
{this.state.pma.map((Item, index) => (
          <this.props.typePma
            key       = {index}
            ref       = {(child) => { child.display(Item)}}
            onDelete  = {() => this.onDelete(index)}
            />
          ))}
```

But if I'm just updating the data even without changing it, like:

```
  appendNewPma(){
    var newPma = this.state.pma.slice();
    //newPma.push(this.props.typePma);
    this.setState({pma:newPma})
  }
```

I've get exception error on this line:

```
 ref       = {(child) => { child.display(Item)}}
```

It complains that child is None (TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of null
).

But why?!!! Why the logic change when there is no change: The data are not changed, just redisplayed. Why the ref is sending me null object where it is obvious the ref should always give me the instantiated object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the caveat that the [React docs explain](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats). Your ref callback gets called twice - with the actual element and with null afterwards.

Comment: So what should I do? And why my callback I called twice? I just call this.setState like asked in the documentation. But yes, I can confirm they are called twice like you said.

Comment: just check for child being null before calling the `display` method.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. But that's not really sexy on code reading. Why reactjs can't prevent this in the first place? I mean, it is obvious that nobody want a wrong callback call with the wrong type. And not inlining the function make unnecessary steps. Thank you for your help anyway, that really helped me!

Comment: the way I understand it, the null argument call is meant to give you a chance to do clean up of the DOM element references you may have stored.

Comment: The docs say that the ref callback is passed `null` first, not "afterwards" as you have said.

Comment: Correct, I should have elaborated on this further to avoid spreading false info. The docs say that the ref will be called twice *during updates*: first with null, and then again with the DOM element. Including the initial render, this results in DOM, null, DOM,( null, DOM...) sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Petyo has already [pointed you in the direction of the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48946864/2088135) which explain the situation you have come across, but I would suggest that you change your approach, rather than blaming the library.

The whole point of a `ref` is so that the parent can have a reference to the child. Ideally, these should be used as little as possible but in some cases it is unavoidable. In your case, instead of saving the ref, it looks like you are using it as a sort of broken `componentDidMount`.

Why not just change the child component to call its `display` method when it is mounted and/or updated? Additionally, you should consider whether the "display" behaviour can itself be moved into a separate component.

Comment: To be honnest with you, I don't understand a thing about reactjs. Like now, I have another problem: When I update a value from my controller, it updates all the value of all the component in the render. Worst is that the elements display their old state value ignoring the change. I didn't thought it will be such a headeach and I start regretting using it.

Comment: I'm not going to try and persuade you to use React if you don't want to but what I would recommend is that you take some time to learn how it works before you complain about it being broken, just because it doesn't do what you guessed it would. Good luck!

Comment: But I still need to thank you. I stopped using the ref things, and instead make the update from the view itself (and not the controller) via the componentDidMount like you suggested. This is far far better.